# search:relationship field

Tags: search

I'm in need of a way of searching by a relationship. Its not possible out of the box according to the docs, but is there a workaround?

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="products"
{if get:service}search:product_service_name:url_title="{get:service}"{/if}
}
```

Product Service Name being the relationship.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Low Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-search) is an add-on that makes search a lot more powerful and does provide filtering on relationship fields.  Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using EE 2.6 or newer, you should be able to do this without using the `search=""` parameter.

What's you're really looking for is the parent entries (those with the relationship field and have the target entry selected).

From the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#accessing-parents), you can access parents like this. (Slightly modified for your situation)

```
{exp:channel:entries url_title="{get:service}" dynamic="no"}
        {parents field="product_service_name"}
                {!-- Do whatever you need to do in here --}
        {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```